# Python process has 100% CPU usage and can't be stopped

Tags: centos, kill

I have a python process running on a CentOS machine.

I the process is running with 100% CPU usage and status 'R'.

I tried to kill it with kill -9 PID but it didn't work.
How can I kill the process?
[image]

Comment: If that is the only process with `python` in its line, then have you tried using `pkill -f python` ?

Comment: It didn't work too. The process is a python script with pytorch (but nvidia-smi doesn't show gpu usage)

Comment: Status R means it's running. Usually that means it's interruptible and thus killable. Is your user the same as the one executing the process?

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes (the owner userid is mine), however process was executed with slurm srun command.

Comment: Do you have access to perf top?

Comment: No, it is not installed and I don't have sudo rights

Comment: https://researchcomputing.princeton.edu/faq/how-to-kill-a-slurm-job

Comment: The process got executed by slurm and then canceled so it doesn’t appear on slurm anymore